# Show that the formulas have even number of paranthesis

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

> Using **structural induction,**
>
> **Show:** All propositional logic expressions contain an even number of parentheses. (0 is considered an even number)

**Base Case:** Let $p$ be a propositional letter, then we have $p$ has 0 parantheses, thus even.

**Inductive**: We show for complex-er statements.

**(1)** Take: $(\neg p) \space$ then **How do I use the hypothesis?**

I don't see a way of formally saying $(\neg p)$ must have even # of parantheses, so what is the inductive way?

Comment: The induction is on the *complexity* of the formula, i.e. on the number $n$ of occurrences of connectives. For $n=0$, you have done it. Now, assume it true for all formulas $\varphi, \psi$ with $n$ connectives and consider the two cases with $n+1$ connectives: $(\lnot \varphi)$ and $(\varphi \lor \psi)$.

Answer (score 3):

You do *structural induction* on this one, meaning that you prove that:

Base case: it is true for all atomic propositions (you did this, good!)

Step:  You assume (inductive hypothesis) that the claim is true for $\varphi$ and $\psi$, and show that the claim will be true for $\neg \varphi$, $(\varphi \land \psi$), $(\varphi \lor \psi)$, $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)$, and $(\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi)$